# Gnome 3 keyboard shortcuts sometimes stop working until reboot

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

This in Debian Stretch. It is very annoying, as I have multiple shortcuts, such as going to home directory, taking screenshot etc., which stop working altogether, until I reboot the computer. I have work open, many applications, tabs etc., I can't just reboot the computer. Is there a process or demon that can be killed and restarted?

Comment: Any luck finding a solution? I'm in a similar situation, but only one of the keyboard shortcuts stop working until I change the key combo and then change it back to the original that was not working (in my case I have `passmenu` set to `<Super>i`). Strangely, other shortcuts I have for things like terminal are not affected and always work without any issue.

Comment: @francium No, did not find a solution except reboot.

Comment: happens for me on gnome-shell-3.30.2 as well

Comment: Same problem here. As an alternative one can re-set them in the Keyboard shortcuts configuration. Then they work for a while again.